# Post data from input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, dom

Hope that i can get an answer...i'm trying to post an input value in this format. I want to be able to get the entered text, not the character that replaces the text. Input type="password" is not a solution.

```js
var text = "";
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e){
 
  if(e.which === 8){
   text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
  }
  
  var data = $(this).val();
  $(this).val( data.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*@!?^<>{}\w\s]/g, '●'));
  
});

$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(e){
 text += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="newname" type="text" id="txt1" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: It looks like this is what you're trying to achieve https://www.sitepoint.com/better-passwords-1-the-masked-password-field/

Comment: I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: Thanks. How can i mark as best answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about Changing `keypress` to `keydown`? since `keydown` event always fire before `keyup`

Comment: Forgot to mention that type="password" is not a solution for me. I edited my question. Thx